# Filling externals forms in a Phonegap app like 1Password does

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, form-submit

My boss told me that I've to fill an external HTML form loaded in an iframe in a Phonegap Application with Javascript, but I don't think that is possible for security reasons. But I've seen in the App Store apps like **1Password** that can do what I want. 1Password fill external forms and execute the submit button. How can I do something like that? How 1password could avoid the security reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS 8, 1Password put together an app extension that developers embed in the app. Thus, 1Password can only fill out forms in apps that it's included in. It's able to fill out native and web views.

More information can be found here: https://blog.agilebits.com/2014/07/30/introducing-the-1password-app-extension-for-ios-8-apps/

If the PhoneGap app is your company's and you can modify the source, you may be able to manipulate the content in the iframe (depending of XSS protection). If the JavaScript is external to the app, you may be out of luck.